# Posts page template: How can I edit the markup for this?

Tags: posts, templates, blog-page

I have in settings->reading changed the front page to display a static page. One for home, one for news with a custom template for each. Home works fine, however News will not change no matter what I change.

Can anyone give me clear instructions on how to control/change the 'latest posts page' so I can change the markup.

Thanks

Comment: make sure current theme doesn't have `home.php` file. if exists. rename or delete it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [index.php template is used instead of blog page](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113506/index-php-template-is-used-instead-of-blog-page)

Comment: Check out the [WordPress template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and [the template hierarchy cheat sheet](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/legacy/090_WPCheatSheets/WP_CheatSheet_TemplateMap.jpg).